# Dynamic element unable to select rest of DOM?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, bootstrap-4

I have a button that is dynamically added via jquery. The button exists on each row of my table and I now need to add functionality to them. The problem is that I can't seem to select the parents of my dynamically added button!

I have tried to use jquery to get the text of the fourth parent of the button, this returns a big jquery error indicating that I broke everything.

```
var result = $(this).parents().eq(3).text;
alert(result);
```

this function is called via this:

```
$(document).on('click','#addcommentbtn',function(){
addcomment();
});
```

The text that I'm trying to fetch is four steps above the button, so I use .parents().eq(3) to select it, but it doesn't work for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide code that you made ?

Comment: I think i added it above :). If there's anything else essential apart from that lmk of what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The $(this) in your function addcomment() is not the #addcommentbtn element. So either you need to pass the this as an argument to addcomment and use it like in my below example

```js
function changeColor(thisRef) {
 $(thisRef).parent().addClass("alt");
}

// handle click and add class
$("button").on("click", function(){
  changeColor(this);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```